# Calculate the degree of a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Find degree $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]$

let $a = \sqrt{2}$

$a^2 = 2$

$\therefore a$ is a root of $q(x) = x^2 -2$, where $q(x)\in\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})[x]$

means degree of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})$ is $\leq 2$

If degree is $1$ then $a\in\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})$, which clearly not possible as $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2}) = [{a+bi\sqrt{2}|a,b,\in\mathbb{Q}}]$

$\therefore$ Degree of $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})]$ is $2$

Does this makes sense?

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself? It helps so we have an idea what kind of answer to give (ie. do you just need a push in the right direction, or do you not even know what a field is).

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far_

Comment: Close-voters --- this is a new user --- please give OP a chance (say, 24 hours) to respond to comments and improve the question.

Comment: More of a push, I know how to do $[\mathbb{Q}(i√2):\mathbb{Q}]$ just stuck on the second one

Comment: I put what I have tried so far, got stuck bit further along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second one, remember that we're thinking of $\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt 2)$ as an extension of $Q(i\sqrt2)$, not of $\mathbb Q$. Writing $K=\mathbb Q(i\sqrt 2)$, what can you adjoin to $K$ to get $\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt 2)$? Then you just need to look for the minimal polynomial of that element over $K$.

In fact, you can show that it suffices to adjoin either $i$ or $\sqrt 2$ to $K$. You can find the minimum polynomial of either of those over $K$ the same way you would find their minimum polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.

To show that $K(i)=\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt2)$ (for example), use the definition that, when $F$ is any field and $a$ is an element of an extension of $F$, $F(a)$ is the smallest (by inclusion) extension of $F$ that contains $a$. So $K(i)$ is the smallest extension of $K$ that contains $i$. Well, $\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt2)$ is an extension of $K$ that contains $i$, so therefore $K(i)\subseteq\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt2)$. But $K(i)$ also contains both $i$ and $\sqrt2$ (since $K$ contains $i\sqrt2$, so just divide that by $i$). So it's an extension of $\mathbb Q$ containing both $i$ and $\sqrt2$, and therefore contains the smallest such extension $\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt2)$. So $K(i)\supseteq\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt2)$.

Comment: I added some work to the second part.

Comment: @WD-40 The biggest problem is that you never justified why $K(a)=\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt 2)$. Also, the part after "clearly not possible" isn't sufficient.

Comment: How do you show $K(a) = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$ where $a = i$ or $\sqrt{2}$. I know what needs to be written for the second part of your comment

Comment: @WD-40 I think what you wrote for $F(\sqrt2)$ is wrong, but I think that's basically the right idea. However, I was thinking of something simpler which I'll edit into my post.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;f(x)=x^2+2\in\Bbb Q[x]\;\;\text{is irreducible}\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;g(x)=x^2-2\in\Bbb Q(i\sqrt2)[x]\;\;\text{is irreducible}\end{align*}$$